# Finding the nth value of a dual series

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a problem which i remember solving using Z transform in my uni. time, but i don't recall the EXACT way.

I have 2 series of numbers:
X[n] and Y[n]

X[0] = Y[0] = 1

X[n+1] = aX[n] + bY[n]
Y[n+1] = cX[n] + dY[n]

How can i find the nth value of X?

Comment: This is probably a reasonable question for [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com) if you say a bit about what you've tried, but it does not belong on MO, which is for research-level mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

the recursion
$$X(n+1)=aX(n)+bY(n),\;\;Y(n+1)=cX(n)+dY(n),\;\;X(0)=Y(0)=1,$$
is solved by
$$X(n)= 2^{-n-1}Z^{-1} \left((Z-a-2 b+d) (a+d-Z)^n+(Z+a+2 b-d) (a+d+Z)^n\right),$$
$$Y(n)= 2^{-n-1}Z^{-1} \left((Z+a-2 c-d) (a+d-Z)^n+(Z-a+2 c+d) (a+d+Z)^n\right),$$
with $Z=\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}$.